# Grails excel import

Tags: excel, grails, file-upload, import

I want to import excel file in my application there is a plugin for this operation in grails, that plugin is not supporting my version of grails 1.3.7 can anyone give me yo valuable solution for my prob?

Answer (score 1):

1. Use the [source code](https://github.com/jbarmash/grails-excel-import) and adapt it to your version of grails
2. The plugin is build around [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/), so you could include the library and write your own code. Here's on [reading and writing](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#ReadWriteWorkbook).

**Updated**:

The [grails plugins SVN](http://svn.codehaus.org/grails-plugins/grails-excel-import/tags/) has multiple tags for this plugin, including versions compatible with 1.3.x

Comment: Ya thanks Nicolas Modrzyk, but my doubt id will it work if i use that source code which is written for grails version 2.0 can i use those built-in functions in my application without that plugin ??

Comment: I have added a link to another SVN repository with the proper source code.

Answer (score 1):

The grails excel importer 1.0 works only with 2.0. For grails 1.3.7 use version 0.9.5. For this run the install plugin command as grails install-plugin excel-import 0.9.5. We also ran into problem for the joda-time dependencies. So we installed joda-time 1.2 plugin as well.

Answer (score 0):

We have successfully used http://grails.org/plugin/excel-import plugin with Grails 1.3.7. Let us know if you run into any issue with that plugin